# Java Regex to accept anything within qualifier

Tags: java, regex

I need a bit tricky java regex pattern to achieve the following.

Accept anything wihtin the qualifier say "$$" Something like below does most of the job:

```
Pattern rc = Pattern.compile("[\\$\\$].*[\\$\\$]");
```

This will accept strings like : `"$$ANYTHING$$"` , `"$$A$@#$@NYTHING!!!$$"` etc.

However I want to prohibit : `$$abc$$xyz$$` as it contains `"$$"` in the middle! Please tell me a way to achieve this. Also `$$$$xyz$$` and `$$xyz$$$$` should be rejected

Comment: The input string always starts and ends with `$$`?

Comment: Putting things in square brackets seems to be a common mistake.  I don't really know why.  Square brackets in a regex mean "match **one** character, if the character is one of the characters listed inside the square brackets".  So the pattern `[\\$\\$]` will match a single `$`, not the two-character `$$` sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^\\$\\$(?:(?!\\$\\$).)*\\$\\$$
```

Just add anchors and a negative lookahead to make sure `$$` is not in middle.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/8

The problem with your regex was `[\\$\\$]` will accept `$` only one time as it is inside character class and without `^` and `$` it will not be strict with boundaries. Also `.*` will accept anything that is why your second `$` was getting accepted.

`(?:(?!\\$\\$).)*` makes sure `$$` does not occur in between.

### Edit

If count of `$` is not fixed use

```
^\\$+(?:(?!\\$).)*\\$+$
```

Comment: Great Tool! Your pattern satisfies most of the cases except this one : $$xyz$$$ This should be accepted.

Comment: You were 15 seconds faster +1

Comment: @anubhava the one you provided was failing for $$xyz$$$ as well. but thanks

Comment: Hmm may be you just needed: `^\\${2}[^$]*\\${2}$"`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at it is there are not 2 "$$" after the first $$:

```
^\\$\\$(?!(.*?\\$\\$){2}).*\\$\\$$
```